SQL Server: which data file extension should be used when adding a primary file on another drive?
If I have a Windows disk with a capacity of 1T, for example, and the primary datafile (.mdf) for my database reaches the disk's maximum size, I want to add a second datafile to the primary group.
As this second datafile is isolated on another disk, can it be of type .ndf? If I create this second file of type .mdf, could there be any performance or operational problems other than just the fact that conventionally only one .mdf should exist?
(I'm not talking here about the logs (.ldf), which are separate on their own disk).

Convention is the only thing dictating your... well... naming convention.
You're free to name the files anything. The on-disk extension doesn't matter.
Consider:
create database foo
    on (
        name = foo,
        filename = 'D:\MSSQL\Data\DBA-343369\foo.mdf'
    );
go
alter database foo
    add file (
        name = TheSecondMdf,
        filename = 'D:\MSSQL\Data\DBA-343369\TheSecondFile.mdf'
    );
go
alter database foo
    add file (
        name = RandomExtension,
        filename = 'D:\MSSQL\Data\DBA-343369\.'
    );
go


That said, I'd recommend you stick with normal convention and make all files other than the first ".ndf". It might be hard-coded into some utility scripts or something you end up using someday and there's no need to shoot yourself in the foot here (unless you want to).

Thank you for your reply. It confirms my initial thoughts. I still had my doubts about SQL Server's use of internal pointers to the various files leading to access problems. As the .mdf file is (normally) the first file, I was afraid that by creating 2 of them, the instance engine would have trouble knowing which file to start reading the pages from.

@Louis, a database has exactly one primary data file, with an mdf extension by convention. Secondary data files should have extension ndf. This is documented here. The naming conventions should be followed to help other DBAs supporting the database,

It is possible that your system admins created a rule on the virus scanner on your server to exclude database files (they normally should :-) ) . So it is important that you use in this case the standard files extensions for SQL server. This is for 1° file .MDF, other data files .NDF and log fil .LDF.
But like already answered, you're free to use any extension you want.
